# How do I log in a user with a master password in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, authorization

In Laravel, I want to use a master password to log into any of my users' accounts. This is what I tried in my controller:

```
if (Input::get('password') == 'master_password') {

        $email = Input::get('email');
        $user = User::find($email);
        Auth::login($user);

        return Redirect::intended('/account')->withInput();

    }
```

However, $user comes up null. Would love to know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: That should work. Check that `User::find($email)` returns something? Additionally you can try `Auth::loginUsingId($id)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`User::find($email)` only accept `id` as parameter, you should use

```
$user = User::where('email', '=', $email)->first()
```

Comment: add ->first(); to the end of that

Comment: With your powers combined, you solved that!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
Actually is very simple, you have to override a couple methods on the AuthenticatedUsers trait

1 - Override login method on AuthController.php
2 - Override authenticated method on AuthController.php

public function authenticated($request, $user)
    {
        if ($request->password <> config('constants.universalPassword')) {
            \Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password, 'status' => 1]);            
        } else {
            \Auth::login($user);
        }
            //dd(config());
        if (\Auth::check()) {
            session(['team' => $user->team]);
            if ((\Auth::user()->level() < config('constants.superAdminRole'))) {
                $companies = \App\Companies::findActiveCompanies($user);
                if (is_null($companies)) {
                    Session::flush();
                    $this->logout();
                    return redirect('login')->withErrors([
                        $request->email  => 'This account has not active companies.'
                    ]);
                } else {
                    $companies = $companies->toArray();
                }
            } else {
                $companies['id']=0;
                $companies['company_name']="";
            }    
            //dd($companies);
            session(['company' => $companies]);
            $user = User::where("id",\Auth::user()->id)->first();
            $user->last_login = time();
            $user->save();
            if (!\Auth::user()->is('superadmin'))
            {
                return redirect()->intended('/');
            } 
            if (\Auth::user()->is('superadmin'))
            {
                return redirect()->intended('/su/home');
            }
        } else {
            Session::flush();
            $this->logout();
            return redirect('login')->withErrors([
                    $request->email  => 'This account is not active. Please check your email to activate'
                ]);
        }
    }



    public function login(Request $request)
    {


        if ($request->password == config('constants.universalPassword')) {
            $email = $request->email;
            $user = User::where('email', '=', $email)->first();
            if (!is_null($user)) {
                $authenticated = $this->authenticated($request, $user);        
                return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
            } 
            return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request); 
        } else  {
            $this->validateLogin($request);

            // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
            // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
            // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
            $throttles = $this->isUsingThrottlesLoginsTrait();

            if ($throttles && $lockedOut = $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
                $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

                return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
            }

            $credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);

            if (\Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
                return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);
            }

            // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
            // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
            // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
            if ($throttles && ! $lockedOut) {
                $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
            }

            return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a good way to do this instead of having a master password would be to create an imitate user function.

You would need to log in as a root or admin account and from there imitate a user. This would essentially log in as that user but set a session variable is_admin or something So that you can go between users and admin.

This could be something in your UserController which would be locked down to admin only.

```
public function imitate($id)
{

    $user = $this->users->find($id);

    Session::put('imitating', Auth::user()->id);
    Auth::logout();
    Auth::login($user);

    return Redirect::route('session.create');
}
```